# Ionic framework - hide left menu button

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a problem with Ionic Framework.

HTML of my app:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-title>
                <img src="img/Logo.png" class="logo">
            </ion-nav-title>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-footer-bar></ion-footer-bar>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

When I run my app, I can see menu button on the left side, but I don't want it. How can I hide this button permamently?

Comment: You can try start from scratch a new project and to test only this ion-side-menu. In this case, the button appears?

Answer (score 0):

Which menu button is it that you see on the left? In your code it's set up correctly to show on the right. In any case, to hide a button, you could add `ng-show="false"` as an attribute to your `<button>` element.

Comment: Take a look at this image please: http://i.imgur.com/fK51lZT.png

As you can see, there is menu button on the left side, which I haven't set anywhere. It doesn't trigger any action, it's just shown.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions for you:

1. removing `<button>` tag i.e. `<button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>` will help.

If you don't want to remove `<button>`:

2. add `ng-show="$root.showMenuIcon"` to button & set the following code in controller(such as menuController) :

   ```
   $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (e) {
      $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = false;
   });
   ```